# Conditional auto-deploy based on git tag in gitlab CI

Tags: git, deployment, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm setting up a deployment process for my website with gitlab CI. 
I have a `production` website and a sub-domain with a `staging` deployment.

Let's say I have different branches among them : master and release. I have a file .yaml that is configured such that : 
if I push on master, I have a deployment on `production` (with a manual option) and if I push on my branch release, I have an automatic deployment on `staging`.

```
git push origin master
```

deploys to production (with manual validation),

```
git push origin release
```

deploys to staging. And any other branch that are pushed do not deploy.

We are several guys to work and, sometimes, we would like to be able to deploy another branch (e.g. `feature`) on `staging` when specifying a tag (e.g. `specifictag`) on a git push :

```
git tag specifictag    
git push origin feature --tags
```

This would be useful for me because sometimes some developers would like to test their codes before merging to release and we don't want to create a third environment. And of course we don't want to deploy every time we push on any branch.

```
stages:

  - staging

  - production

test-deployment:

  stage: staging

  script:

    - [...]

  only:

    - release

  tags:

    - extranetserver

prod-deployment:

  stage: production

  script:

    - [...]

  only:

    - master

  tags:

    - extranetserver

  when: manual
```

Has anyone an idea on how to use tag as a way to force a deployment when a specific tag is pushed ? 
Thanks!

Comment: What kind of website is getting deployed. Which server. Just asking to see if the original problem can be solved differently.

Comment: It doesn't precisely answer your question but have you looked into Review Apps https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/review_apps/ ?

Comment: Thank you guys for your questions and suggestions. Our web-app is very diversified, it gathers many algorithms and features in different languages, so I'm looking for something quite general and adaptive. We call our website a "lab" because of these many features.

Comment: @Jawad : I hadn't looked into ReviewApps when I asked, it looks interesting! However, I'm not sure it could help me, since if I understand well it creates another websites 'subdomain' every time. And I feel I would not like to do so. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Actually you define the way it's deployed. It could be on a subdomain but it could also be on your staging subdomain but on a different port. I think it's been mostly designed to be used with a platform such as kubernetes or openshift which can create subdomains on the fly. So might not be applicable straight out of the box for your use case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use regex, like

```
test-deployment:
    only:
        - /^staging-/
```

And tag your commit, begin with "staging-". When you push, the job should run.

Comment: It works very nicely and it is exactly what I intended to do. Thank you.